# Missing connection_alias argument in django-haystack and elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Django-haystack with elasticsearch missing 'connection_alias' argument.

I am setting up a django app, with django-haystack using elasticsearch for the search engine backend. However, 'connection_alias' argument is missing in the module

The **HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS** in the *settings.py* is setup with elasticsearch

```py
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchBackend',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    }
}
```

And the *search_indexes.py* model is setup below as well:

```py
from haystack import indexes
from .models import Post


class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().published.all()
```

However, when running the *rebuild_index* command in the manage.py for django apps:

```
./manage.py rebuild_index
```

An error occurs showing that there is a missing argument for 'connection_alias'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 41, in handle
    call_command('clear_index', **clear_options)
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 148, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/clear_index.py", line 52, in handle
    backend = connections[backend_name].get_backend()
  File "/home/giddyupyup/Documents/Development/Python/projects/blogapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 109, in __getitem__
    self.thread_local.connections[key] = load_backend(self.connections_info[key]['ENGINE'])(using=key)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'connection_alias'
```

Is there any additional setup needed for the haystack environment to work properly?

I'm using this Django Setup environment:

```
Django==2.2
django-haystack==2.8.1
elasticsearch==5.5.3
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably fixed the issue but for everyone who falls here the simple reason it happens is because you need to specify the **Engine** and not the Backend.

```
...
'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
...
```

See https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/settings.html#haystack-connections